# ImageResizer minwidth / minheight for ebay images

Tags: imageresizer

Ebay now requires images to be 500x500.

I want to try to use [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) to resize an image to be a minimum of 500x500 by adding white background padding

The following command achieves this quite easily.

```
product.jpg?width=500&height=500&scale=canvas
```

This works great, except when the original image is 800x800 and it will be downsized and lose quality.

What I really want to do is combine `scale=canvas` with `scale=upscaleonly` but that doesn't seem to be possible? Am I missing something or will I have to write code myself using the API.

PS. I realize ebay may detect whitespace and still reject the image, but I'm trying that for now - I have a lot of perfectly good 450x450 images that fall short and I don't want to upscale them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### At present, there's no 'upscalecanvasonly' mode.

So far we haven't had anyone else request this, but feel free to add it to our [UserVoice site](http://resizer.uservoice.com) as a feature idea.

You could also implement this with a small IPlugin that subclassed BuilderExtension and implemented LayoutImage to support an additional command. It shouldn't be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ImageResizer before, but I've worked with images, so I took a quick peek at the basic commands for ImageResizer.

If I understand your problem correctly, when you downsize a 800x800 image it looses quality.  This does point to a severe problem because the original image has more data than what is needed to display a high quality 500x500 image. Because of this, we must look at the image file format type and the data compression quality/method.

In your example, you are using the JPEG file format. You may want to specify the format in the command, i.e., **format=jpg**

In using the JPEG format, Imageresizer gives you control over the quality of the compression:
The documentation states:

> quality - Jpeg compression: 0-100 100=best, 90=very good balance, 0=ugly

Take a look at the documentation for the exact verbage for setting the quality.

Comment: appreciate the comments, but I guess what I really meant was that you lose resolution. when you go to Amazon / ebay they'll show you an image resized to 500x500 but when you click on it you'll see the original size. so if I run every image through the querystring I specified above you'll lose resolution